# Hex bytearray to string

Tags: php

Originally from Java: `dumptofile += String.format("%02X", c[icounter]);`

How would I get the output of that back into a string with PHP? (or python, but java isn't going to run on target system)

Comment: See [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: do you want a string that contains the characters 0 to 9 and A to F or are you wanting to get the ascii (or what ever format) value for the characters such as [this](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Comment: I want to get whatever the plaintext was (incl all the \n and etc) from the original string that only contains 09af

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($c)-1; $i+=2)
    $str .= chr(hexdec($c[$i].$c[$i+1]));
```